# AWS elb in ansible scritp is not assigning the vpc id which I already assigned to my security group and subnets

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

We have common vpc created for all our project. I have created the subnets and security group using the vpc manually.

I do the automation for creating ELB. I create the elb using ansible script.
If I create elb with the security group and subnets, it is assigning the `default vpc` instead of the `custom vpc` we have used for our subnet.

We tried to assign the *custom vpc* as well as using *vpc_id* which is not supporting.
We get the *`Security group "sg-0567" does not belong to VPC "vpc-7456as"`* error. It is trying to create the elb with default vpc.

Please advise how to assign the our *custom vpc* which is already created by us during the automation

Comment: please add a sample ansible playbook which you used for creating elb in the question.

Answer (score 2):

There is no separate parameter to pass the `vpc-id` when creating ELB. The vpc is assigned based on the `subnet-id's` you provide in the template.

**Sample template snippet**:

```
instance_ids:
  - i-abcd1234
region: us-east-1
subnets:
  - subnet-abcd1234
  - subnet-1a2b3c4d
listeners:
  - protocol: http
    load_balancer_port: 80
    instance_port: 80
```

If `subnet-abcd1234` and `subnet-1a2b3c4d` are part of `vpc-abcd1234`, then the ELB is automatically assigned to that VPC. When you dont pass any security-group, the `default security-group` of that VPC is assigned to the ELB automatically.

Done forget to pass the `region`. It is always a good practice. If not specified then the value of the *AWS_REGION* or *EC2_REGION* environment variable, if any, is used.

When you get the `Security group "sg-0567" does not belong to VPC "vpc-7456as"` error, then it means the security-group which you are passing in the script to the ELB is not part of the VPC which the ELB is assigned. ie. Your security-group and Subnet are *NOT* part of same VPC.

Remember security-groups can span across multiple subnets but not across multiple VPC.

Comment: Thank you after specifying the subnets and security group belong to the same vpc it worked fine  Below are the sample code

Comment: - name: Create the ELB 
   ec2_elb_lb:
        name: itg-ansible-elb
           state: present
           region: us-west-2
           subnets:  'subnet-2368'
           listeners:
             - protocol: http
               load_balancer_port: 80
               instance_port: 80
           security_group_names: "{{elb_sec_group}}"
   register: elb